# IzPack: how to customize uninstaller window - change size, remove icons?

Tags: izpack

My question is - is it possible to change IzPack uninstaller window - change size, remove icons, maybe put the same logo as it is possible to do for example in HelloPanel.

Answer (score 2):

`is it possible`? Yes. To the small extent that i've used IzPack, i found it very flexible. once you have an idea of its framework, as it exists, you can tweak it quite alot.

as for the uninstaller, you'll need the **source files**, which can be found at https://github.com/izpack/izpack.  get the files from this link, modify the required `.java` files, compile them and place the `.class` files in the appropriate folder in `standalone-compiler.jar`.

i'd suggest you start with `UninstallerFrame.java` which can be found under

`izpack-uninstaller/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/uninstaller/gui` @ [above link](https://github.com/izpack/izpack)